# How to stop the python turtle from drawing

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Can anyone tell me why this code always has a line on the screen and also how to stop it?

Slight problem with this is that every time this happens, I always get a line on my canvas no matter what I try to do. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Now this is probably too much code, but I have no idea how else to show the failing code. I have tried a variety of ways but none seem to work.

```
def drawpixel(x, y, colour):
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.dot(1, colour)

def main():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.title('Mandelbrot set drawer')
    screen.bgcolor('#22ccaa')
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.tracer(-10000, 0)
    turtle.speed(0)
    width = int(turtle.numinput('Screen size', 'What width?', 600, 100, 20000))
    height = int(turtle.numinput('Screen size', 'What height?', 600, 100, 10000))
    turtle.setworldcoordinates((-width)//2, (-height)//2, (width)//2, (height)//2)
    radius = 2
    turtle.goto((-width)//2, (-height)//2)
    x, y = ((-width)//2, (-height)//2)
    while y<((height)//2 +1):
        while x!=((width)//2 +1):
            newx = x/(width//2)*radius
            newy = y/(width//2)*radius
            mpos = newx + newy*1j
            drawpixel(x, y, getcolour(mpos))
            x += 1
        y += 1
        turtle.goto((-width)//2, y)
```

Maybe the getcolour is failing so here is the code for it:

```
def iterc(c):
    iters = 0
    z = 0+0j
    while iters < 16 and math.hypot(z.real, z.imag)<2:
        z = z*z+c
        iters += 1
    return iters

def getcolour(pos):
    x = iterc(pos)
    colournum = int(x*6.25)
    colour = 'gray{}'.format(colournum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked your code to get rid of the line and fix other issues that I saw:

```
def main():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.title('Mandelbrot Set')
    screen.bgcolor('#22ccaa')

    width = int(screen.numinput('Screen size', 'What width?', 600, 100, 20000))
    height = int(screen.numinput('Screen size', 'What height?', 600, 100, 10000))
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-width // 2, -height // 2, width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.tracer(0, 0)

    radius = 2

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')

    x, y = -width // 2, -height // 2
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    while y < (height // 2):

        while x < (width // 2):

            newx = x / (width // 2) * radius
            newy = y / (width // 2) * radius
            mpos = newx + newy * 1j
            drawpixel(x, y, getcolour(mpos))
            x += 1

        x, y = -width // 2, y + 1
        screen.update()
```

Despite its title, I don't picture this drawing a Mandelbrot but it should at least *scan* correctly.

**UPDATE**

Now that you've provided `getcolour()`, the Mandelbrot nature of this becomes clear.  Below is the complete reworked code and some output:

```
import math
import turtle

def iterc(c):
    iters = 0
    z = 0 + 0j

    while iters < 16 and math.hypot(z.real, z.imag) < 2:
        z = z * z + c
        iters += 1

    return iters

def getcolour(pos):
    x = iterc(pos)
    colournum = int(x * 6.25)
    return 'gray{}'.format(colournum)

def drawpixel(x, y, colour):
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.dot(1, colour)

def main():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.title('Mandelbrot Set')
    screen.bgcolor('#22ccaa')

    width = int(screen.numinput('Screen size', 'What width?', 600, 100, 20000))
    height = int(screen.numinput('Screen size', 'What height?', 600, 100, 10000))
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-width // 2, -height // 2, width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.tracer(0, 0)

    radius = 2

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')

    x, y = -width // 2, -height // 2
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    while y < (height // 2):

        while x < (width // 2):

            newx = x / (width // 2) * radius
            newy = y / (width // 2) * radius
            mpos = newx + newy * 1j
            drawpixel(x, y, getcolour(mpos))
            x += 1

        x, y = -width // 2, y + 1
        screen.update()

main()
```

OUTPUT (reduced in size, still not finished running)

[image]

Neither the prettiest nor the fastest implementation but it is a Mandelbrot.

Now that you've seen your code works on my system, you need to review your environment (Python version, Windows or Unix, etc.) to see what's different.  The above was done with Python 3.6.0 on Max OSX 10.11

Comment: Not sure why, but when I run the code, nothing is draw even after waiting for a while for the screen update. Also what the the other issues and the getcolour function does the calculations for it.?

Comment: @Lasagnenator, I copied my code from this page; added an `import turtle` at the top; added a `main()` call at the bottom; copied over your `drawpixel()` function; added my own `getcolour()` function that simply returns `'red'` since you didn't provide one and it runs fine.  It simply fills the screen with red dots as I would expect without your `getcolour()`.

Comment: I followed the same steps as you and got no result, just a cyan screen with no drawings on it. My python version is 3.6.2 so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: @Lasagnenator, I doubt that the difference between 3.6.0 and 3.6.2  has anything to do with your lack of output -- most turtle code still runs unmodified under Python 2.7.  I'll think about your issue but have no answer for you at this time.

Comment: I installed a fresh copy of python 3.6.2 and ran the code but still has the same problem with just a cyan screen and nothing else. maybe my graphics card is not strong enough for python? It is a cheap laptop I'm running on but even when I run it in 3.5.2 on a beafy computer I get the same result. What could be the problem then?

Comment: The environment that I'm running on is Windows 10 home and using the pyhon.org install with two custom libraries and a few site-packages. Not sure why the python build makes turtle behave differently in Mac compared to Windows.

Comment: @Lasagnenator, there are differences in tkinter, upon which turtle is built, between Windows and OS X.  One known one is fill operations (e.g. filling a segmented five pointed star.)  Another Windows oddity that comes up with turtle/tkinter on SO is when incorrect graphics driver software doesn't show diagonal lines, just horizontal and vertical.

Comment: So does this mean that this code will not work on Windows unless some new graphics driver is installed but will work on OS X? Why can't both builds have the same functionality and run in the same way? It would be great if the python developers could change this unless someone has a fix.